# post import hooks in python 2.7

Tags: python

According to [PEP 369](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0369/), post import hooks should be implemented for python 2.6 and 3.0. However, I am unable to register or execute any import hook (according to PEP) in python 2.7. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I'm curious about this. Could you post some code, what you expect to do, what it actually does?

Comment: @agf: found out that the PEP is actually in draft stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PEP is currently in draft stage, hence there's no support for post_import_hooks for the time being. I missed the part about the status, and I thought it was already approved.